# How to use scikit learn inverse_transform with new values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a set of data that I have used scikit learn PCA. I scaled the data before performing PCA with StandardScaler().

```
variance_to_retain = 0.99
np_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_data)
pca = PCA(n_components=variance_to_retain)
np_pca = pca.fit_transform(np_scaled)

# make dataframe of scaled data
# put column names on scaled data for use later
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled, columns=df_data.columns)
num_components = len(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
cum_variance_explained = np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)

eigenvalues = pca.explained_variance_
eigenvectors = pca.components_
```

I then ran K-Means clustering on the scaled dataset. I can plot the cluster centers just fine in scaled space.

My question is: how do I transform the locations of the centers back into the original data space. I know that StandardScaler.fit_transform() make the data have zero mean and unit variance. But with the new points of shape (num_clusters, num_features), can I use inverse_transform(centers) to get the centers transformed back into the range and offset of the original data?

Thanks, David

Comment: did some further reading. just input your centers into the inverse_transform function

Answer (score 8):

you can get cluster_centers on a kmeans, and just push that into your pca.inverse_transform

here's an example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler



iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

scal = StandardScaler()
X_t = scal.fit_transform(X)

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(X_t)
X_t = pca.transform(X_t)

clf = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
clf.fit(X_t)

scal.inverse_transform(pca.inverse_transform(clf.cluster_centers_))
```

Note that sklearn has multiple ways to do the fit/transform.  You can do `StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)` but you lose the scaler, and can't reuse it; nor can you use it to create an inverse.

Alternatively, you can do `scal = StandardScaler()` followed by `scal.fit(X)` and then by `scal.transform(X)`

OR you can do `scal.fit_transform(X)` which combines the fit/transform step

Comment: And after that use `inverse_transform()` on the scaler to get the original unscaled data back.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. That works as you say *if you do not rescale the data* with StandardScaler().fit_transform(). My understanding is that it's good PCA practice to rescale data that have very different ranges. So the question remains, how do I back transform the *scaled* cluster centers to the original data range?

Comment: Running inverse_transform() on the scaled centers has the wrong dimensions for the scaler object: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (4,) (3,3)"

Comment: you're probably doing the inverse in the wrong order.  check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

**Here I am using SVR to Fit the data before that I am using scaling technique to scale the values and to get the prediction I am using the Inverse transform function**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  

#Creating two objects for dependent and independent variable 
ss_X = StandardScaler()
ss_y = StandardScaler()

X = ss_X.fit_transform(X)
y = ss_y.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))

#Creating a model object and fiting the data
reg = SVR(kernel='rbf')
reg.fit(X,y)

#To make a prediction
#First we have transform the value into scalar level
#Second inverse tranform the value to see the original value
ss_y.inverse_transform(reg.predict(ss_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]]))))
```

Comment: It is important to note that there are two scaling operations which is what is correctly shown: 1) for features (e.g. X) and 2) for the target (e.g. y). Trying to scale them with a single operation will produce inconsistencies when inverting the scale for the predictions which are only the y values.